# Toplevel window appearing before rest of function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've got a button that I'd like to be able to click and have a toplevel window appear to say 'Processing..' while the rest of the function runs.

Not sure why, but the toplevel window only appears AFTER the rest of the function has done its thing.

I've tried messing around with time.sleep() and such, but no dice.

```
class newFrame():

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame_main = Frame(master)
        frame_main.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)

        self.scan_button = Button(master, text="Scan", command=MasterScan)
        self.scan_button.grid(row=5,column=1))

def MasterScan():

    top = Toplevel()
    msg = Label(top, text="Processing...")
    msg.pack()

    button = Button(top, text="Cancel", command=top.destroy)
    button.pack()

    #Rest of the function starts here - web scraping stuff
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Never use .sleep with tkinter.  Use .after instead.  See examples in multiple tkinter answers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding top.update() in with the rest of the function seemed to do the trick!

Comment: tk is event-looped based.  The mouse click on button event is handled by calling the associated command.  The pack event is not handled until the function returns, unless you direct otherwise.